# Revision v0.0.0: Unknown for go get k8s.io/kubernetes

Tags: ubuntu, go, kubernetes

How do I solve this problem?

```
$ go mod init
$ go get k8s.io/kubernetes@v1.15.5
go: k8s.io/kubernetes@v1.15.5 requires
        k8s.io/api@v0.0.0: reading k8s.io/api/go.mod at revision v0.0.0: unknown revision v0.0.0
```

Environment is:
`go 1.13`
`ubuntu 16.04`

Comment: Please look at this: [Github Issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32776)

Answer (score 3):

Go to version go1.16.7 linux/amd64.

This issue occurs because the dependency for kubernetes requires k8s.io/api v0.0.0 which is not present- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/ddc4ed03657d6c8c009a5d915265d00cadcb634c/go.mod#L155

So we have to find the specific versions for what we require
This dependency list fixed issue for me.

```
require github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator v0.0.0-20210902044020-c6c97a176521

replace (
    k8s.io/api => k8s.io/api v0.19.6
    k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver => k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver v0.19.6
    k8s.io/apimachinery => k8s.io/apimachinery v0.19.6
    k8s.io/apiserver => k8s.io/apiserver v0.19.6
    k8s.io/cli-runtime => k8s.io/cli-runtime v0.19.6
    k8s.io/client-go => k8s.io/client-go v0.19.6
    k8s.io/cloud-provider => k8s.io/cloud-provider v0.19.6
    k8s.io/cluster-bootstrap => k8s.io/cluster-bootstrap v0.19.6
    k8s.io/code-generator => k8s.io/code-generator v0.19.6
    k8s.io/component-base => k8s.io/component-base v0.19.6
    k8s.io/cri-api => k8s.io/cri-api v0.19.6
    k8s.io/csi-translation-lib => k8s.io/csi-translation-lib v0.19.6
    k8s.io/kube-aggregator => k8s.io/kube-aggregator v0.19.6
    k8s.io/kube-controller-manager => k8s.io/kube-controller-manager v0.19.6
    k8s.io/kube-proxy => k8s.io/kube-proxy v0.19.6
    k8s.io/kube-scheduler => k8s.io/kube-scheduler v0.19.6
    k8s.io/kubectl => k8s.io/kubectl v0.19.6
    k8s.io/kubelet => k8s.io/kubelet v0.19.6
    k8s.io/legacy-cloud-providers => k8s.io/legacy-cloud-providers v0.19.6
    k8s.io/metrics => k8s.io/metrics v0.19.6
    k8s.io/sample-apiserver => k8s.io/sample-apiserver v0.19.6
)
```

Comment: Why is Kubernetes behave like that? I've never seen such `v0.0.0` tagging. Why they don't act like anyone else? This mess the `go.mod` file unnecessary. Could you expain me that please?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run it after running below script:

```
#!/bin/bash

VERSION=${1#"v"}
echo $VERSION
if [ -z "$VERSION" ]; then
  echo "Please specify the Kubernetes version: e.g."
  echo "./download-deps.sh v1.21.0"
  exit 1
fi

set -euo pipefail

# Find out all the replaced imports, make a list of them.
MODS=($(
  curl -sS "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/release-1.24/go.mod" |
    sed -n 's|.*k8s.io/\(.*\) => ./staging/src/k8s.io/.*|k8s.io/\1|p'
))

# Now add those similar replace statements in the local go.mod file, but first find the version that
# the Kubernetes is using for them.
for MOD in "${MODS[@]}"; do
echo "Download $MOD"
  V=$(
    go mod download -json "${MOD}@kubernetes-${VERSION}" |
      sed -n 's|.*"Version": "\(.*\)".*|\1|p'
  )

  go mod edit "-replace=${MOD}=${MOD}@${V}"
done

go get "k8s.io/kubernetes@v${VERSION}"
go mod download
echo "done"
```

run with script and pass version like "v1.24.0"

More details here: https://suraj.io/post/2021/05/k8s-import/