# how do i debug the dependency tree?

Tags: go

Given following code wannabe-compiled with `go1.17.1`, what are the steps to apply to fix the dependency tree and build the program ?

```
/*
Copyright 2021 The Kubernetes Authors.
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"

    "sigs.k8s.io/kpng/client"
)

func main() {
    client.Run(printState)
}

func printState(items []*client.ServiceEndpoints) {
    fmt.Println("# ------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    fmt.Println("#", time.Now())
    fmt.Println("#")
    for _, item := range items {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, item)
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
$ go mod init test.com/example
go: creating new go.mod: module test.com/example
go: to add module requirements and sums:
    go mod tidy
$ go mod tidy
go: finding module for package sigs.k8s.io/kpng/client
go: found sigs.k8s.io/kpng/client in sigs.k8s.io/kpng v0.0.0-20210917162839-ef6a4c0272e2
go: sigs.k8s.io/kpng@v0.0.0-20210917162839-ef6a4c0272e2 requires
    k8s.io/kubernetes@v1.21.2 requires
    k8s.io/api@v0.0.0: reading k8s.io/api/go.mod at revision v0.0.0: unknown revision v0.0.0
```

Unfortunately the few commands i was able t gather from [the documentation](https://golang.org/ref/mod) could not help me to move forward on my issue. What can i do ?

```
$ go mod graph
$ go mod verify
all modules verified
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59187781/revision-v0-0-0-unknown-for-go-get-k8s-io-kubernetes/69296723#69296723) and [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32776)

Comment: ultimately it brings to [this example](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cloud-provider-huaweicloud/blob/master/go.mod) (not sure if that can be the final solution, I never used that package)

Comment: @blackgreen yeah, good catch, for this specific problem the solution is to apply the replace directive of the problematic package into the top `go.mod`. Assuming the dependency is known to build and usually works, to summarize, the steps to proceed further on such issue would be like 1/ identify the package with problematic imports 2/ get their go.mod /3 imports their replace directives into the top level go mod.

Comment: @blackgreen unfortunately i believe this will not work in that case https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.22.1/go.mod#L499